# Sed does not work in expect

Tags: linux, bash, sed, expect

I made this bash one-liner which I use to list Weblogic instances running along with their full paths.This works well when I run it from the shell.

```
/usr/ucb/ps auwwx | grep weblogic | tr ' ' '\n' | grep security.policy | grep domain | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | sed 's/weblogic.policy//' | sed 's/security\///' | sort
```

I tried to incorporate this in an expect script

```
send "echo Weblogic Processes: ; /usr/ucb/ps auwwx | grep weblogic | tr ' ' '\n' | grep security.policy | grep domain | awk -F'=' '{print \$2}' | sed 's/weblogic.policy//' | sed 's/security\///' | sort ; echo ; echo\r"
```

but I got this error sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'

Please help

Comment: Yikes! Show us some sample output from ps so we can simplify that pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without careful counting or testing, I'd try adding another `\` after "security\", or possibly deleting the existing one.

Also, you can combine the two seds into one: `sed -e 's/weblogic.policy//' -e 's/security\///'`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `\` character in

```
sed 's/security\///'
```

needs an extra escape in expect context, e.g.

```
send "echo Weblogic Processes: ; /usr/ucb/ps auwwx | grep weblogic | tr ' ' '\n' | grep security.policy | grep domain | awk -F'=' '{print \$2}' | sed 's/weblogic.policy//' | sed 's/security\\///' | sort ; echo ; echo\r"
```

Comment: The same is probably true for all other backslashes in the string.

Comment: @Aaron, no just this one is problematic. All the others are escaping something special to expect. That backslash needs to be protected to pass to sed.

Answer (score 1):

Use Tcl's {} operator instead of double quotes around the string you want to send. The {} syntax in Tcl is equivalent to single quote in bash, meaning "literal string, do not interpret its contents".

Inside the {} put exactly what you want Tcl/Expect to send to the subprocess, character for character, no extra quoting required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is too complex to send over to a remote host. Instead, put the commands in a small shell script and execute that. This way, you won't run into trouble because of quote expansion rules, escaping, etc.

Moreover, you should use `ssh` instead of `expect` to run scripts. `expect` is for running interactive commands like `ftp` which don't have suitable scripting abilities.

Comment: I need expect since I have to run this on multiple servers remotely and I cannot use OpenSSH Public Key in my setup.

Answer (score -1):

you can try removing the single quotes and run the command again.

```
send "....... sed s/weblogic.policy// | sed s/security\/// ..."
```

Its most probably quoting issues. If its not ok, try the suggestion  by `hlovdal`

meanwhile, some of your longish commands can be combined

```
/usr/ucb/ps auwwx |grep weblogic| tr ' ' '\n'|awk '/security.policy/&&/domain/{gsub("weblogic.policy|security","",$2);print $2}|sort
```

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the syntax in your command.It dint work out